# EXC_BAD_ACCESS EXC_I386_GPFLT while click on button

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

i have a `UIViewController` with `UITableView`, when the tableView is empty i want to show another view so i am using this

```
    [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
    NoKidsViewController *noKids = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoKidsView"];

    [self.view addSubview:noKids.view];
```

all is fine, i'm able to see the view. but when i tap on one of the buttons in it i'm getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS  EXC_I386_GPFLT` error.

```
//NoKidsViewController

    - (IBAction)addNewKid:(id)sender {
        AddKid *addKidController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddKid"];
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:addKidController animated:YES];

    }

    - (IBAction)saleSpot:(id)sender {
        SaleSpot *saleSpotController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddKid"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:saleSpotController animated:YES];
    }
```

i searched the net over 3 hours trying to find any solution w/o success. what could cause that error? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `noKids` controller is going out of scope and being deallocated. This is what is often referred to as a zombie object.

You need to add the `noKids` controller to the `childViewControllers` of the containing controller.

```
NoKidsViewController *noKids = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoKidsView"];
[self addChildViewController:noKids];
[self.view addSubview:noKids.view];
[noKids didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This will retain the `NoKidsViewController` as well as allow the view controller methods to pass down to it. For more information on creating your custom container view controller:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html