# Xcode: Determine caller of function in xcode in debug

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

How can I determine where some function called in debug state? I'm in stuck with EXC_I386_GPFLT error hence I do not expect invocation such function with my test case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of exception code "EXC\_I386\_GPFLT"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651788/whats-the-meaning-of-exception-code-exc-i386-gpflt)

Comment: Also check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268744/exc-bad-access-exc-i386-gpflt-while-click-on-button

Answer (score 1):

You can try new Xcode 7 feature called `Address Sanitizer`.

In Xcode go to `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`, select `Run`, open `Diagnostics` tab and check `Enable Address Sanitizer`.

[image: Address sanitizer]

Then `Product -> Clean` project and run it again.

> Objective-C and C code is susceptible to memory corruption issues such
>   as stack and heap buffer overruns and use-after-free issues. When
>   these memory violations occur, your app can crash unpredictably or
>   display odd behavior. Memory corruption issues are difficult to track
>   down because the crashes and odd behavior are often hard to reproduce,
>   and the cause can be far from the origin of the problem.
>
> You enable the address sanitizer in the build scheme. Once enabled,
>   added instrumentation is built into the app to catch memory violations
>   immediately, enabling you to inspect the problem right at the place
>   where it occurs. Other diagnostic information is provided as well,
>   such as the relationship between the faulty address and a valid object
>   on the heap and allocation/deallocation information, which helps you
>   pinpoint and fix the problem quickly. The address sanitizer is
>   efficient—fast enough to be used regularly as well as with interactive
>   applications. It is supported in OS X, in the Simulator, and on iOS
>   devices.

[New features in Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html)