# Go back to original Root View Controller from a third tier Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, rootviewcontroller

I have some storyboards setup as below:

**Storyboard A**

--> Root Navigation Controller --> Container View Controller --> View Controller --> Home View Controller --> Storyboard B Reference

**Storyboard B**

--> Container View Controller --> Navigation Controller --> View Controller --> Storyboard C Reference

**Storyboard C**

--> Navigation Controller --> View Controller

The gist of it is, I load the app and the `rootViewController` is set. I then browse through the app and end up in `Storyboard B` which contains a button that takes me to `Storyboard C`. On the `View Controller` in `Storyboard C` there is a button that I want to take me back to the start of the app.

How, from the `View Controller` in `Storyboard C`, can I get back to the `Home View Controller` in `Storyboard A`?

***Things I have tried:***

```
[self.navigationController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

---

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:nil];
```

---

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;
```

---

The above 3 all go back to the right place but then the app crashes with `EXC_I386_GPFLT`.

I have also tried a few other things that didn't work. I know this is probably something very simple and i'm just having a bad day. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated right now.

Comment: I would prefer first method, anyway try putting an exception breakpoint and check where its crashing, also post any crash log you get

Comment: Adding an exception breakpoint was one of the first things I did but it offered no assistance. it just crashed in the main.m file. Also, I don't seem to be able to find anything in the logs. I will have to continue the hunt after lunch.

Comment: if you add any view controllers view as a subview, make sure that you added it as child view controller too  for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268744/exc-bad-access-exc-i386-gpflt-while-click-on-button

Comment: I managed to find and add a couple of logs that appeared after the crash on my device. I will take a look into your last comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved it by performing the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method on the main thread:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:nil];
```